# Get access to variables set in AIML in AIMLbot.dll

Tags: aiml

I'm just getting started using the AIMLbot.dll library with C#.  I'm wondering if there is a way to access the variables that are set using `<set name="foo">bar</set>`.  I'm hopefully looking for a way to set a callback function inside the `<think>` tags when just before displaying the response from the bot, check to see if the variable name `callback` contains any value and if so, perform that function before returning the result to the end user.

I've checked all the elements that makeup the active bot object in Visual Studio but I haven't seen anything that alludes to the place these variables are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.

When you use `<get>` and `<set>` in your AIML, the value for the variable is set under the 'User.Predicates' option.  Happy to report callbacks are working as they should.